# Selecting all points inside polygon in PostGIS?

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table samplecol that contains (a sample):

```
vessel_hash   | status | station | speed |  latitude   |  longitude  | course | heading |        timestamp         |                      the_geom                      
--------------+--------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 5     | -5.41844510 | 36.12160900 | 314    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:31:04.000Z | 0101000020E61000001BF33AE2900F424090AF4EDF7CAC15C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 3008    | 0     | -5.41778710 | 36.12144900 | 117    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:43:27.000Z | 0101000020E6100000E2900DA48B0F424042C3AC61D0AB15C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 17    | -5.42236900 | 36.12356900 | 259    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:50:27.000Z | 0101000020E610000054E6E61BD10F42407C60C77F81B015C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 17    | -5.41781710 | 36.12147900 | 230    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:27:03.000Z | 0101000020E61000004D13B69F8C0F424097D6F03ED8AB15C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 61    | -5.42201900 | 36.13256100 | 157    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:08:04.000Z | 0101000020E6100000CFDC43C2F71042409929ADBF25B015C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 9     | -5.41834020 | 36.12225000 | 359    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:33:03.000Z | 0101000020E6100000CFF753E3A50F42408D68965F61AC15C0
```

I try to fetch all the points inside the polygon with:

```py
poisInpolygon = """SELECT samplecol.latitude, samplecol.longitude
FROM samplecol
WHERE ST_Contains(samplecol.the_geom,('POLYGON((-15.0292969 47.6357836, -15.2050781 47.5172007,
-16.2597656 29.3821751, 35.0683594 26.1159859, 38.0566406 47.6357836, -15.0292969 47.6357836))'));"""
cursor.execute(poisInpolygon)

exists1 = cursor.fetchall()
count1 = 0;
for ex1 in exists1:
   count1 = count1+1
   print ex1,"\n"
   print "points", count1
```

---

But this returns zero results although I know that inside this polygon many points exist.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set the SRID of you search envelope to 4326 and you need to explicity convert the WKT representation to a geometry, ie, `ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;`'POLYGON((-15.0292969 47.6357836,....-15.0292969 47.6357836))'). To be honest I am surprised you are not getting an error along the lines of no function exists ST_Contains(geom, text), although from your code snippet, perhaps you don't have an error handler round the function  call.

Comment: you mean something like: ST_Contains(samplecol.the_geom,(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326; 'POLYGON((-15.0292969 47.6357836,-15.2050781 47.5172007,-16.2597656 29.3821751, 35.0683594 26.1159859, 38.0566406 47.6357836,-15.0292969 47.6357836))'))) ??

Comment: Can you please provide the full query? I cannot figure it out. I try this: poisInpolygon = """SELECT col.vessel_hash,col.longitude,col.latitude from sampelcol as col,                ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((-15.0292969 47.6357836,-15.2050781 47.5172007,-16.2597656 29.3821751, 35.0683594 26.1159859, 38.0566406 47.6357836,-15.0292969 47.6357836))'),  ST_GeomFromEWKT(col.the_geom)) FROM samplecol As col;""" but returns: (103079215291L, Decimal('40.87011000'), Decimal('29.20170000'), False) . Why returns False?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer need to parse comments. Perhapse if you write out the SQL legibly, you'll notice the error of constructing a geometry from a geometry.

Comment: While you must build a PostGIS geometry from the WKT presentation of your reference polygon your "samplecol" table does already contain PostGIS geometries and ST_GeomFromEWKT(col.the_geom) does not make sense at all. col.the_geom is what you need.

Comment: Because you put ST_Contains in the wrong place, it should be in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You're messing up the order in the ST_Contains fuction.

*ST_Contains(geometry geomA, geometry geomB):*

*Geometry A contains Geometry B if and only if no points of B lie in the exterior of A, and at least one point of the interior of B lies in the interior of A.*

So your polygon and samplecol.the_geom need to switch places in the ST_Contains function.

for more information: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html